# How to return PHP array and receive it with Java

Tags: java, php

I have this on my webservice:

```
 function listar($username)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM APKs WHERE Tipo=0");
    //$registo = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $numero = 0;
    while($registo = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $regs[$numero] = $registo['Name'];
        $numero++;
    }

    return $regs;

    //return mysql_fetch_array($result);

}
```

in Java, after the SOAP call (not relevant now) I read it this way:

```
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
String x = response.toString();
```

I need to access which one of those fields (selected from the database) so I thought, why not split the array into strings?

I tried two methods:

```
String[] arr=x.split(&quot; &quot;);
        System.out.println(&quot;Array :&quot;+arr.length);
        for(int i=0;i&lt;arr.length;i++)
        {
            ..
        }

        StringTokenizer stArr=new StringTokenizer(x,&quot; &quot;);
        while(stArr.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            ...
        }
```

But none of them worked, whick make me believe I'm returning badly the array in first place.

Any help?

**UPDATE:**

- So I'm using again xsd:string;
- Now I have on my webservice return json_encode($regs);
- To convert the object from the response I'm using a specific google api
  http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

  Object response =  envelope.getResponse();
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String jstring = gson.toJson(response);
- But I'm with difficulty parsing the "jstring" because it's format: "[\"SOMETHING\",\"SOMETHING\",\"SOMETHING\",\"SOMETHING\",.....]". I have not any identifier to get those values.

How can I extract those dynamic values and assign them to String[]?

Answer (score 2):

USE:

json_encode($array);  in PHP

and

JSONObject in Java to read.

See this example: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

**UPDATE**

Change the line:

```
$regs[$numero] = $registo['Name'];
```

to:

```
$regs[] = array('name' => $registo["name"]);
```

If you need to get the ID, you also can do:

```
$regs[] = array('name' => $registo["name"], 'id' => $registo["id"]);
```

FORGET:

The mysql_fetch_array returns a real array not a string. It's not needed to split a string.

1. Be sure that your PHP Web Service is returning a xsd:array
2. Generate a new proxy using some generator like http://www.soapui.org. Just use the proxy. Nothing else.

Comment: I edited the function listar because it was return a multi dimensional array. I was returning xsd:string indeed. Corrected. Use proxy? Why? And how? I've no idea what you are suggesting.

Comment: Proxy it's a design pattern. Some proxy generator will generate Java classes that will the dirt work for you and return a clean Array.

Comment: Follow this link: http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/01/29/generating-a-web-service-proxy-client/

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have no idea how to apply this in my java android client... much because that tutorial is to create a web client.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mentioned that you were using Android, so I think the best way it's use a simpler approach like JSON.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't. Can you please specify a link or two? Just to know what I should be looking for. One way or another I need to receive that as an objective because I'm using KSOAP2.

Comment: I inserted again in the response:USE:

json_encode($array); in PHP

and

JSONObject in Java to read.

See this example: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Comment: When using String jstring = gson.toJson(response);
   JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jstring); I get json exception that string cannot be converted to json object.. I believe it's the sintax from the returned string from the webservice.

Comment: Have you tried using my updated suggestion? See if you can read this json: http://www.gammarh.com.br/pocs/teste.php

Comment: Of course. Indeed I have exact the same json format that the one from that website - and that, don't work too, I have the same exception... :(. Armando, usei todas as tuas sugestões - o que se tornou agora irrelevante, porque coloquei aquele json numa jstring, e dá-me a mesma excepção. Eliminei várias linhas de código para o caso de existir algo em "conflito", a verdade é que em JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jstring); , aquele JSON não é aceite - que por sinal é "igual" ao meu...

Comment: It need to be this way: JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jstring); ir order to accept. However it works with that static jstring, with mine does not work, I think it's because the " instead the '.

Comment: Also the json array returned it was not accepted by java notation, I had to do jstring = jstring.replace("\"[","[");
   jstring = jstring.replace("]\"","]");
   jstring = jstring.replace("\\\"","'");

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSON and you can esy build easy object and read it.

Comment: One part was specified by @armandomiani and what about android you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html for this case